# Twitter Authorization/Authentication in Servicestack asking to Authorize every time

Tags: twitter, authorization, servicestack

When using GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider, the authorization/authentication flow for Google is to authorize the first time, but each time thereafter it just authenticates. For instance:

1) Website app goes to /auth/googleopenid
2) Google prompts to authorise the app against the account, click Accept
3) Sent back to app

If you logout and then go back to step (1), step (2) is skipped, as you would expect.

With TwitterAuthProvider, step (2) - having to click the "Authorize app" button - happens every time. This makes logging in as twitter less convenient.

See an example with Servicestack's own demo:

http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/

Other answers I've found say that it should be calling Twitter's "oauth/authenticate" and NOT "oauth/authorize".

So, is there a way to configure Servicestack to work this way, or is it just a bug?

Comment: As a workaround I have overriden the Twitter provider so I can replace the redirect from being "/oauth/authorize" to "/oath/authenticate". Seems to work, but would like to know the proper way.